# class method to ask for userinput

Tags: java, class, methods

I am really pretty new to java and have a homework assignment due in a couple days. Unfortunately when my teacher try's to help me out I just still don't understand it. I need to create two classes to compute a discounted loan and then a main class to call them all and actually make it work. This is my first class its all correct based on what the teacher wants.

```
package Project2;

public class Loan {


    public double money;
    public double interest;
    public double loanperiod;
    public double totaldiscount;

    public Loan(){
        money=0;
        interest=0;
        loanperiod=0;
            }
    //set money,interest,and loanperiod
    public void setmoney(double newmoney){
        money=newmoney;
    }
    public void setinterest(double newinterest){
        interest=newinterest;
    }
    public void setloanperiod(double newloanperiod){
        loanperiod=newloanperiod;
    }
    //get money,interest,and loanperiod
    public double getmoney(){
        return money;
    }
    public double getinterest(){
        return interest;
    }
    public double getloanperiod(){
        return loanperiod;
    }
    public double gettotaldiscount(){
        return totaldiscount;
    }
}
```

The second class I need to create another object. Then I have to create a method to compute the discounted loan and a method to describe the program, a method to get userinputs and a method calling the correct method from from the loan class above to display the output.

So far this is what I have for the second class, just a description method. But I am really confused as to how I am going to make a method to compute the discountedloan (I have the formula), and how to create a method to get userinputs. If I could get any help at all I would appreciate it. But please explain I really want to learn this rather then copy.

```
package Project2;

public class DiscountedLoan {

    public DiscountedLoan(){

    }

    public void description(){
        System.out.println("This program computes the proceeds of a discounted loan. Loan amount is in dollars and cents, Annual interest rate is in percentage, and the loan period is in number of years.");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of object oriented principles you need to understand. The first is the idea of what a class is. A class is a thing. You have the definition, or the actual code, that represents the 'design' of the thing. It does stuff (methods) and has state (variables). An instance of a class is an actual implementation.

You can apply this principle to the real world easliy. For example, a car has a design somewhere. Engineers create models, CAD drawings etc and that is comparable to the coded class. At some point that design is turned into an actual car that is comparable to an instance of a class when your program runs.

In your code you have created a class definition for loan. It is just the design for what a loan looks like but doesn't actually contain any loan data. So when your program runs you need to create an instance of that loan to represent an actual loan. You can then use the methods of that class to populate the details, i.e. money, interest, etc.

When writing a method you need to decide a couple of things. What data does my method need to do its work and what data will it give back to me. In this case you may want to write a method that takes in a loan and returns a number to represent the discount. Your other method really just needs to display the user interface and call the appropriate methods with the right data.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to read in integers that a user enters.

```
public int getLoanFromUserInput(){
  try{
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
     System.out.println("Enter a loan balance: ");
     int n = reader.nextInt();
  }catch(TypeMismatchException e){ 
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so i have to create a method with that in my second class. How would I go about that?

Comment: I would read @Gremash's answer. Then review what a class is and how to define methods within classes.

Comment: Alright I think I understand it a bit better one question though if i want to call something to the second class I have to create a object for it correct? Because I think I almost have it I have the method getting the user input but now I need to call a method from the first class and put it in this class and then set the method to what ever the user input is.